# Waiting for all threads spawned by my code under test in JUnit test case

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing, junit

How do I ensure in a JUnit test case, that all the the threads spawned directly/indirectly by the method under test are done with there job, so that I can assert the final result?

```
@Test
public void testMethod() {
 Result result=method();// may spawn multiple threads to set result.value

 Assert.assertTrue(result.getValue()==4); //should execute only after result.value is set to its final value.
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real question is, how do you deal with this case in your non-test code?  What does the API of `method()` guarantee to its callers about when `result.value` will be set?

Bear that in mind strongly when writing tests - the purpose is to assert that the class and its methods behave as they advertise.  Sometimes, working out what the advertised interface is can be half of the challenge.

In a situation like this, I would strongly recommend that your `Result` object behave like a `Future`, in that its `get()` method blocks until the result is available.  (Alternatively, give it a `waitFor()` method or similar).

If your method doesn't provide any specific guarantees or blocking calls, all you can *really* do in the test is to keep checking the value every *x* seconds in a loop, putting a `@Timeout` on the test to ensure that the value is set in a "reasonable" time.  But this is all a client would be able to do too, so

1. it's a very valid test;
2. it highlights that the interface isn't very usable for clients and modifying it would be a nice idea.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you invoke the Thread#join on multiple threads instances in method(),follow this way,all sub threads are completed.