# Testing threaded lambda function in spring controller

Tags: multithreading, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have a simple endpoint in a controller, as it is:

```
private final ExecutorService threadPoolExecutor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(6);
@PostMapping(path = "/batch")
public ServiceResponse batch(@RequestBody BatchRequest request) {
    threadPoolExecutor.submit(() -> {
        try {
            service.batch(request);
            log.info("Batch finished");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Failed to execute. Cause: ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
    return ServiceResponse.asSuccess("Ok");
}
```

This has been done like this because the service may take minutes to run, so we avoid locking the whole system. I'm trying to make a unit test for this and catch it's exception (increasing code coverage). This is what I came up until now

```
@Rule
public ExpectedException exception = ExpectedException.none();

@InjectMocks
private MyController controller;

@MockBean
private MyService service;

@Test
public void testBatchThrowsException() throws Exception {
    createRequest();

    when(service.batch(any())).thenThrow(Exception.class);


    mockMvc.perform(post(Controller.URL_PREFIX+"/batch")
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(request.toString()))
            .andDo(MockMvcResultHandlers.print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
    exception.expect(Exception.class);
}
```

But of course it returns success as the thread is still going when the request ends. Is there someway to mock the executor and get the results or something like that? I've tried using Awaitility, but I can't call the lambda function properly.

Answer (score 0):

In order to "return something" the only thing you can do is to change implementation of controller code (maybe with usage of Future or something else).

However, if you can't do it, the idea may be to delay main thread in test case, then check if specific method is called.

If you can't change implementation of real code my advice is:

- below call to controller in test class - delay main thread with Thread.sleep or something else
- throw **mock** of exception from service
- verify production behaviour using mockito: count calls of printStackTrace() on exception mock, count calls on service
- optionally - make timeout on test, to be sure that it lasts expected period of time

Moreover, read [Waiting for all threads spawned by my code under test in JUnit test case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513104/waiting-for-all-threads-spawned-by-my-code-under-test-in-junit-test-case)